# Synthesis of 5 bar mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, linkage

I'm working on my university project but I can't find a proper  synthesis method for 5 bar mechanism. I'm working on underactuated mechanism. It's a slider crank with the connecting rod divided into 2 links with a pin joint. Thanks!!!![image]

Comment: Diagrams of such things always help

Comment: Hope this helps. The slider A is the input and Crank CD is output

Comment: That is a 6 bar linkage.

Comment: Can you please explain me? @joojaa thanks!

Comment: A-B, B-C, C-D, C-G, G-F, F-E are links, and thus there are 6 links. Either your description is wrong or your picture is wrong

Comment: GCD is a single link. C-E-F-G is a 4 bar mechanism. I'm unsure about how to synthesise A-B-C-D. It's not a regular slider crank. I hope this helps!! I'll try to get you a better diagram

Comment: oh yes, now its clearr. Usually you draw such things as a triangle too, as the mechanism drawings are idealisations of real mechanisms. Or then you draw a thicker bow over the link. In either case this is a six bar linkage, more importantly its a inversed variation of a watt 1 linkage.

Comment: it would have been possible if the long link(the one with 3 joints) would be divided in two parts. that would have made it into watt 6 bar linkage. but I'm unable to understand what to do under these conditions. i havent found similar examples. Could you help me out? @joojaa

Comment: You need to calculate the frame as one link (just because you dont draw it out does not mean its not there). If you discount or freeze the slider then this is simply a watt type 1 6-bar linkage [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4GwC.png), your configuration is just the mirror image. This means that the  mechanism is an adjustable 6 bar linkage. So now the question is what links do you dirve? Or if you just drive one then you have in fact a virtual pivot (in which case ist just a simple 6 bar linkage)